XY-MD02 doesn't respond to Modbus RTU queries
I've been programming an Opta Finder as client (master) in order to experiment Modbus RTU.
It's linked to a brand new XY-MD02 sensor (temp and humidity) bought on Amazon.
Both are powered-up with a 18V PSU, the red led in the XY-MD02 is on, the A+/B- cables are properly connected.
I'm trying to read values from the sensor, using sample queries found in the only available datasheet for the sensor.
To do so, I've been using the Arduino IDE. The baudrate variable is set to 9600. The code is a sample code grabbed on the Opta Finder page, that uses ArduinoModbus.h and ArduinoRS485.h. I don't think it would be relevant to share it here, because the query is (at least) correctly sent.
Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

I've plugged my oscilloscope to be sure that the query is sent by the client. For instance, I get with ModbusRTUClient.begin(baudrate, SERIAL_8N2) : 
The queries are exactly the same...But the sensor doesn't respond back.
I've read here that some of the XY-MD02 clones had different parameters for the parity check and the encoding so I also tested ModbusRTUClient.begin(baudrate, SERIAL_8N1) and ModbusRTUClient.begin(baudrate, SERIAL_8E2) without success. The XY-MD02 sensor remains silent.
I was so desperate that I even assumed that the default slave ID was not set to 1, and I tried all the slave ID's from 1 to 247. I also tried a broadcast with ID #O in order to write the ID with the function code 0x06.
What am I missing here ?

My experience of reading a similar modbus sensor (not XY-MD02 but the same SHT20-based temperature/humidity sensor with modbus interface) shows that there is a need for 50ms delay between rs485.begin(baudrate, SERIAL_8N1) and the reading of the temperature sensor. the same 50ms delay is also required for reading subsequent humidity value unless you read the both registers with one single command 0x01, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x20, 0x0B. Let me know if this work?

thanks for your reply, I added this delay in my setup() and changed my command to the one you gave me but I still get no answer from the XY-MD02

Got some problems with the same type of sensor, I would suggest you to use a modbus poll tool such as SimplyModbus to check the command sent in a PC.
Also mine worked with Read Input Register (0x04) instead of Holding Register (0x03), I did it by plugging a RS485-USB adapter and using SimplyModbusRTU to check the command hex. Then once it worked used a Raspberry Tool to automate the query with the correct parameters

I struggled with this as well, in my particular case, I eventually figured out when I pulled the case off that the manufacturer had put the sticker backwards on the case, and I had the B-,A+, V- & V+ wires in the reverse order. Once I wired it up to follow the markings on the PCB instead of the case, I started getting answers.
My XY-MD02 from aliexpress has a red LED on the board that is constantly on when it has power on V- & V+. That was a clue.
